# Variable "character" evaluada como un valor numérico

Tags: r

He creado una función para devolver los elementos de un vector numérico mayores a 10:

```
mayora10 <- function(x) {

   idx <- x > 10   
   x[idx]

 }
```

> mayora10(1:20)

```
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Sin embargo, cuando le doy como argumento a la función un valor character, me devuelve el mismo valor.

> mayora10("a")

```
[1] "a"
```

Lo mismo ocurre si en lugar de 10 evaluara por cualquier otro número.

**¿Por qué?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta es ¿qué ocurre aquí?:

```
"a" > 10
[1] TRUE
```

Si esperabas un error, pues no, R realiza una coerción automática al tipo de dato más inclusivo, en este caso una cadena, por lo que finalmente el código sería algo así:

```
"a" > "10"
[1] TRUE
```

Es decir una simple comparación de cadenas, dónde los números siempre tiene un orden inferior al de las letras, de hecho dónde el `"2"` es superior al `"10"`:

```
mayora10(c("b", "a", "1", "2"))
[1] "b" "a" "2"
```

Si quieres que la función pueda trabajar con cadenas que sean convertibles a números, podrías hacer algo así:

```
mayora10 <- function(x) {
  
  idx <- as.numeric(x) > 10
  x[which(idx)]
  
}

mayora10(c("b", "a", "1", "2", "33"))
[1] "33"
Warning message:
In mayora10(c("b", "a", "1", "2", "33")) : NAs introducidos por coerción
```

Comment: Excelente Patricio, muchas gracias.